# C# DataGridView KeyPress

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have to do a search when a customer types in part of the name name and presses F2.

So, if they type "SMI" and press F2, it should search for SMI and give a list of those that fit that criteria.

Here is my code on KeyPress:

```
private void ScanCheckKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  // Search for customer
  if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F2)
    AccountSearchScreen();
  // Cancel ACH Process
  if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F3)
    if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy) CancelAsyncButtonClick(sender, e);
  // Scan Checks
  if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F5)
    ButtonScanChecksClick(sender, e);
  // Submit & Close Batch
  if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F8)
    ButtonSaveClick(sender, e);
}
```

And AccountSearchScreen method:

```
private void AccountSearchScreen()
{
  if (dgv_Checks.CurrentRow == null) return;
  var dr = dgv_Checks.CurrentRow;
  //var name =      dr.Cells[checkTrans.IndividualCheck.NameOnCheckColumn.ColumnName].Value.ToString().Trim().ToUpper();     
  //dr.Cells[checkTrans.IndividualCheck.NameOnCheckColumn.ColumnName].Value = name;     
  var searchkey = dr.Cells[checkTrans.IndividualCheck.NameOnCheckColumn.ColumnName].EditedFormattedValue == null ? string.Empty :
                  dr.Cells[checkTrans.IndividualCheck.NameOnCheckColumn.ColumnName].EditedFormattedValue.ToString().Trim().ToUpper(); 
  if (searchkey.Length == 0)
  {
    dr.Cells[checkTrans.IndividualCheck.NameOnCheckColumn.ColumnName].ErrorText = "Please enter part of the last name to search.";
    return;
  }

  var cs = new CustomerSearch(searchkey);
  cs.ShowDialog(this);

  if (cs.Branch != null && cs.Branch.Trim().Length == 2 && cs.AccountNumber != null && cs.AccountNumber.Trim().Length == 5)
  {
    dr.Cells[checkTrans.IndividualCheck.NameOnCheckColumn.ColumnName].ErrorText = string.Empty;
    dr.Cells[checkTrans.IndividualCheck.NameOnCheckColumn.ColumnName].Value = cs.NameOnAccount;
    dr.Cells[checkTrans.IndividualCheck.BranchColumn.ColumnName].Value = cs.Branch;
    dr.Cells[checkTrans.IndividualCheck.AccountBalanceColumn.ColumnName].Value = GetAccountBalance(cs.Branch + cs.AccountNumber);
    dr.Cells[checkTrans.IndividualCheck.AccountNumberColumn.ColumnName].Value = cs.AccountNumber;
  }
  else
  {
    dr.Cells[checkTrans.IndividualCheck.NameOnCheckColumn.ColumnName].ErrorText = "No account found for [" + dr.Cells[checkTrans.IndividualCheck.NameOnCheckColumn.ColumnName].Value + "].";
  }
}
```

My problem is when I set the name here:

dr.Cells[checkTrans.IndividualCheck.NameOnCheckColumn.ColumnName].Value = cs.NameOnAccount;

It is not applying. The name still shows "SMI".

I believe I know why, correct me if I am wrong. The reason why it never changes is due to that I am never loosing focus out of the name field when I press F2, it still has focus so the apply edit never occurs until I leave the field. Then the SMI gets applied overwriting the cs.NameOnAccount.

Is that the case?

Either way, how do I fix this problem?

Thanks for the help as usual!

Comment: Is this a WinForm application?

Comment: it's a C# WinForms application

Comment: I can't reproduce but try calling `dgv_Checks.EndEdit();` after you set your DGV Cell values.

Comment: Are you sure your KeyDown event is capturing keystrokes entered in the grid cell while it's in edit mode? I don't see an event for that.

Answer (score 0):

Though I am not certain about why it is not displayed I can share a few points here.

1. Setting a cell value doesn't have anything to do with leaving the cell.
2. From the style of code it could be possible that if (dgv_Checks.CurrentRow == null) return; may cause the control to return before executing other statements. You can either comment this line and see how it goes or debug to see the value of dgv_Checks.CurrentRow. (I can't guess what that is)
3. You may debug to check what's the value of checkTrans.IndividualCheck.NameOnCheckColumn.ColumnName since this serves the index for data row. Also check the value in cs.NameOnAccount.

In summary, debugging your code should provide you better idea and you may post the debuged values if you still don't get an answer to this.

Comment: 1.I understand it doesn't, but if the EditedFormattedValue overwrites the value once you leave the cell then it would. 2. I am getting to the where it is setting the value = cs.NameOnAccount. The NameOnAccount does have a value and it sets the value since it shows it after it sets it. The display isn't updating and the value ends up as SMI after I leave the cell.